# How can I colorize ls on mac os x terminal?

Tags: macos, colors, terminal.app

I've seen everywhere I look:

> Edit .bash_profile on your home directory.

The thing is, I don't have any .bash_profile on my home directory.

At least I do `pico ~/.bash_profile` and I see nothing.

How can I colorize the ls output ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps we can just create it ?

Comment: yes I can indeed create it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit (or create) your ~/.bashrc to include the following:

```
# LS coloring
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

Comment: I've created a .bash_profile and place your lines inside. That worked. Some of my directories, not all, appear as a yellow/gold background - can you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: Those are related with permissions on that folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -la
```

will show you all files in a long format that also includes permissions. Is the file really there? Do you have permission to read it?

Comment: The file isn't there. The only thing similar perhaps is one called ".bash_history"